# SQL SELECT Query for appending an "and" before the last car

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `carDetail` with the following data.

[image: Table]

I just want the records who have Car more than "Jignesh" in following format,

"Gaurav have Audi, BMW, Honda And Toyota car"

```
SELECT concat(`Name`, ' has ', GROUP_CONCAT(car SEPARATOR ', '),' Cars') as
     result
from cardetail
where `Name` IN (SELECT `Name` FROM `cardetail`
                 GROUP BY `Name`
                 HAVING COUNT(`Car`) > (select count(`Car`)
                                        from cardetail
                                        where `Name` = 'Jignesh'))
GROUP BY `Name`
```

and got the result something like this,

[image: Result]

I want "**and**" before last Car, something like this,

```
Gaurav has Audi, BMW, Honda and Toyota Cars
```

If anyone knows the solution, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: this is something that's more easily done at the application alyer

Comment: Why don't you try to achieve this with some programming language? It will be very easy!

Comment: somehow replace last occurence of comma with and

Comment: Use a stored procedure: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-stored-procs.html

Comment: @e4c5 And Harshil : This is the question which is asked me in interview.  i also know that that is done easily on application and programming language side. they are clearly mention that to achieve it via Query.

Comment: @mhasan: yes i know but how that is the problem...

Comment: @BeñatBermejo: Thanks.. for the reference. u got +1.

Comment: people please provide link if has solution instead of down rating. Link will be fine for me instead of direct solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    SET @var := (SELECT concat(`Name`, ' has ', GROUP_CONCAT(car SEPARATOR ' ,'),' Cars') as
         result from cardetail where `Name` IN (SELECT `Name` FROM `cardetail` GROUP BY 
        `Name` HAVING COUNT(`Car`) > (select count(`Car`) from cardetail where 
        `Name` = 'Jignesh')) GROUP BY `Name`);

   SELECT REPLACE(@var,SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, ' ', -2),REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, ' ', -2),',',' and ')) as result
```

Comment: Hi Jignesh M. Mehta.I used your query and added variable.if your query is perfect then it will works fine.

Comment: Many many Thanks for your best answer you got +1. that is working fine but still one small problem is arise I got the result like, Gaurav has Audi, BMW, Honda, and  Toyota Cars , after last Car record it display ','. can we remove it. so i consider your best answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible solution and I absolutely hate it. But it might work.

I just can't test it, so give it a try :

```
SELECT concat(LEFT(result, (LENGTH(result) - LOCATE(',', REVERSE(result)))), ' and ', (RIGHT(result, (LENGTH(result) - LOCATE(',', REVERSE(result))+1))))
FROM
(

    SELECT concat(`Name`, ' has ', GROUP_CONCAT(car SEPARATOR ', '),' Cars') as result
    from cardetail
    where `Name` IN (SELECT `Name` FROM `cardetail`
                     GROUP BY `Name`
                     HAVING COUNT(`Car`) > (select count(`Car`)
                                            from cardetail
                                            where `Name` = 'Jignesh'))
    GROUP BY `Name`
)
```

The idea is:
There's no `InstrRev` function in MySQL that would allow to find the position of the last occurrence of a string in another string, but we can mimic it like this :

```
(LENGTH(result) - LOCATE(',', REVERSE(result))+1)
```

You can then make a `LEFT()` to that position and a `RIGHT()` from that position. and add a `" and "` on the middle

Comment: many thanks for your answer. but it throws an error. Every derived table must have its own alias . will you please check and give me the best answer.